# How can i Insert (Save) Multiple rows from DataGridView to Database in Windows Forms (WinForms) Application using C# and VB.Net

Tags: sql, database, datagridview, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

How can i Insert (Save) Multiple rows from DataGridView to Database in Windows Forms (WinForms) Application using C# and VB.Net

Comment: How can i Insert (Save) Multiple rows from DataGridView to Database in Windows Forms (WinForms) Application using C#  with entity framework

Comment: Google : SqlCommand, SqlBulkCopy, and SqlConnection these three classes that you need to do what you've asked